# ¿Cómo puedo Seleccionar una etiqueta que está en una clase con JS?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentado seleccionar desde JS una etiqueta que está dentro de una clase.
Creo que me extoy explicando mal, lo cual espero que me corrigan.
Lo bueno que con el ejemplo me entenderan xd.

**Código**

```
.clase input {

}
```

Existe el querySelector y el getElementById, pero estos no me dejan colocar esto:

```
document.querySelector(".clase input");
```

Gracias!

Comment: te referis a un input que esta dentro de una etiqueta con la clase 'clase'? funciona bien asi, selecciona el input normalmente

Comment: Tengo una Etiqueta con su clase que se llama clase valga la redundancia jeje. EJ: <input class="clase"><p>texto</p>. Entonces en CSS tengo .clase p {} . Y quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de hacer en JS tipo: document.querySelector(".clase p").

Comment: ah tu te refieres a cuando los elementos son adyacentes verdad?, en ese caso usa document.querySelector('.clase + p') y se selecciona 'p' siempre y cuando este precedido por un elemento con la clase 'clase'

Comment: GRACIAS!, ME HA SERVIDO!

Comment: Gabriel, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta de jachguate, o pídele a infinit3Loop__ que redacte una respuesta como para aceptarla. Recuerda que las preguntas sin respuestas aceptadas vuelven a _relanzarse_ cada cierto tiempo en el inicio.

Comment: @padaleiana ya mismo lo hago

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el selector `input.clase`. En este caso:

- `input` Es el tipo de elemento
- `.clase` es la clase que te interesa.

He preparado este pequeño ejemplo.

```js
function buscarInputsClase() {
  x = document.querySelectorAll("input.clase");
  x.forEach((el) => {console.log(el.id)});
}
```

```css
.clase input {
    background-color: blue;
    text-color: red;
}

.clase::placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="clase" id="i1" placeholder="v1"></input>
<input type="text" class="clase" id="i2" placeholder="v2"></input>
<input type="text" class="clase" id="i3" placeholder="v3"></input>
<input type="text" id="i7" placeholder="v7"></input>
<input type="text" id="i8" placeholder="v8"></input>
<button onclick="buscarInputsClase()">Buscar inputs de la clase</button>
```

Puedes probarlo aquí mismo haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.
Al hacer clic en el botón "Buscar inputs..." va a mostrar el `id` de todos los inputs de la clase, que tienen el *placeholder* en color rojo para una fácil identificación.

Comment: Excelente mi Estimado!

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar elementos adyacentes mediante JavaScript con ****querySelector**** o **querySelectorAll** debes usar el combinador '+' cuya sintaxis basica es *A + B* donde se obtiene *B* siempre y cuando sea precedido por *A*

```js
let paragraph = document.querySelector('.clase + p')
console.log(paragraph)
```

```html
<input class='clase' type="text" title="input"></div>
<p>HOLA MUNDO</p>
```

Tanto **querySelector** como **querySelectorAll** nos permite seleccionar nodos del mismo modo que con CSS, incluso haciendo uso de pseudoclases si lo necesitamos.

Puedes aprender mas sobre los combinadores [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators)